# How can I periodically generate db connection password with nestjs + typeorm?

Tags: node.js, nestjs, typeorm

I followed this instruction (https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database) to setup the Postgresql database connection with nestjs. I created a class to provide the connection options like:

```
export class PostgreeSql implements TypeOrmOptionsFactory{
   async createTypeOrmOptions(): Promise<TypeOrmModuleOptions> {
       const signer = new AWS.RDS.Signer(...)
       signer.getAuthToken({}, (err, token) => {
    ...
}
```

In the above method createTypeOrmOptions, it generates the password which is valid for 15 minutes. It works fine for the 15 minutes but after the password token expire, I will get authorization error response in my application. I have a scheduler to generate a new password every 15 minutes but How can I force nestjs to reconnect with a new connect options?

Comment: have you solved that issue?

Answer (score 0):

NestJS `TypeOrmModule` use `pg` library under the hood, and basically the options you pass are forwarded to the `Pool` constructor inside `pg`. As [explained](https://node-postgres.com/features/connecting) in the `pg` page, connecting using short-lived authentication tokens can be achieved by passing a token generating function instead of a password.

TL;DR:

Register `TypeOrmModule` in your NestJS application like this:

```js
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      useFactory: () => {
        const signerOptions = {
          credentials: {
            accessKeyId: 'YOUR-ACCESS-KEY',
            secretAccessKey: 'YOUR-SECRET-ACCESS-KEY',
          },
          region: 'us-east-1',
          hostname: postgresConfig.host,
          port: postgresConfig.port,
          username: postgresConfig.user,
        }
 
        const signer = new RDS.Signer()
 
        const getPassword = () => signer.getAuthToken(signerOptions)

        return {
          type: 'postgres',
          host: postgresConfig.host,
          port: postgresConfig.port,
          username: postgresConfig.user,
          password: getPassword,
          database: postgresConfig.database,
        };
      },
    }),
```